# Automate Python Script in Microsoft Power Automate

Tags: python, power-automate-desktop

I tried to automate the python script in Microsoft Power Automate to run daily. The python Script is all about doing some enquiries from the newly received emails and fetching keywords and sending all of them as a new email.
The Script is working fine in visual studio code, command prompt.
But not sure what I'm doing wrong in the power automate. This is the first time I'm using power automate. The script is not working seems.. not receiving any output emails.

I have Created two variable first in power automate.

First variable: Path to the python executable
Second variable: Path to my python script
Then run both of them using powershell script. Tried with python script as well. Didn't work

[image]
[image]

Comment: Another option to run script daily is Windows Task Scheduler, you can run the python script directly, via a exe or a batch script

Answer (score 0):

Try the action "Run DOS Command" in Power Automate.

Make sure your Python path is valid in Windows environments.

[image: Action Run Dos Command]